# how to use or format keyword in ebay FindingAPI search

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am using the following code to search items based on keywords:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ConsoleApplication1.EbayServiceReference;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("1001.txt");
            using (FindingServicePortTypeClient client = new FindingServicePortTypeClient())
            {
                MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("My-CustomHeader", "http://www.mycustomheader.com", "Custom Header");
                using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
                {
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
                    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", "myappid");
                    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByKeywords");
                    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

                    FindItemsByKeywordsRequest request = new FindItemsByKeywordsRequest();

                    request.keywords = "gruen wristwatch parts -(sara,quartz,embassy,bob,robert,elephants,adidas)";
                    FindItemsByKeywordsResponse check = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);
                    int totalEntries = check.paginationOutput.totalEntries;
                    Console.WriteLine(totalEntries);
                    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalEntries / 100.00);

                    for (int curPage = 1; curPage <= totalPages; curPage++)
                    {
                        PaginationInput pagination = new PaginationInput();

                        pagination.entriesPerPageSpecified = true;
                        pagination.entriesPerPage = 100;
                        pagination.pageNumberSpecified = true;
                        pagination.pageNumber = curPage;
                        request.paginationInput = pagination;

                        FindItemsByKeywordsResponse response = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);

                        foreach (var item in response.searchResult.item)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
                            tw.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            tw.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("end");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the original keyword set:

> > gruen wristwatch parts -sara -quartz -embassy -bob -robert -elephants -adidas

If i use this keyword set it returns 3 items: The result is [here](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=gruen%20wristwatch%20parts%20-sara%20-quartz%20-embassy%20-bob%20-robert%20-elephants%20-adidas%20&_sacat=0&_odkw=gruen%20-sara%20-quartz%20-embassy%20-bob%20-robert%20-elephants%20-adidas%20wristwatch%20parts&LH_Auction=1&_osacat=0)

I have formatted it like this to use in `FindingAPI` according to this [reference](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/FindingAPIGuide.html#usekeywords)

> > gruen wristwatch parts -(sara,quartz,embassy,bob,robert,elephants,adidas)

and it returns 13 items.  I think it should return 3 items too.
What is responsible for the discrepancy, and can I get the expected results using the alternate syntax?

Comment: Anybody here to answer this ??

Comment: Well, for starters you can just use the original format.